# Why is only one row from this query displayed?

Tags: php, html, sql, printing

I am trying to print the results of this query, but it only prints out the first row. Why is that?

```
if (isset($_GET['consumiperstanza'])) {
    $num_stanza=$_GET['num_stanza'];
    $data1=$_GET['data1'];
    $data2=$_GET['data2'];
    $query="SELECT stanze.num_stanza,consumi.cod_consumo, servizi.nome, 
                   consumi.quantita, servizi.prezzo, consumi.data_c
            FROM consumi, servizi, stanze
            WHERE stanze.num_stanza=consumi.num_stanza
                  AND servizi.cod_servizio=consumi.cod_servizio
                  AND stanze.num_stanza='$num_stanza'
                  AND consumi.data_c BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2'
            GROUP BY stanze.num_stanza";
    $risultato = $conn->query($query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($risultato) > 0){
        echo "<table border=1 bgcolor= 'white' align='center'>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<th>NUMERO STANZA</th>";
                echo "<th>CODICE CONSUMO</th>";
                echo "<th>NOME</th>";
                echo "<th>QUANTIT&Agrave;</th>";
                echo "<th>PREZZO</th>";
                echo "<th>DATA</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
        while($riga = mysqli_fetch_array($risultato)){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $riga[0] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $riga[1] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $riga[2] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $riga[3] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $riga[4] . "</td>";
                echo "<td>" . $riga[5] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table><br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: It should print out every row. There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: Thank you for checking it, but somehow it prints out only the first row

Comment: How many rows of data do you have in this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of your criteria

```
AND stanze.num_stanza='$num_stanza'
```

But you're also doing this.

```
GROUP BY stanze.num_stanza
```

So, you'll only get one group.

---

Additionally, all the other columns in your SELECT are not well-defined since they are not included in the GROUP BY and are not aggregate expressions. [Newer versions of MySQL actually will not allow you to do this by default](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). It is possible in older versions, but may not give you the results you expect.

[The MySQL 5.6 manual:](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html)

> ... this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic.

Comment: So removing group by it should print all rows?

Comment: If you remove group by it _could_ return more than one row. How many rows it does return depends on how much of your data satisfies the criteria (`stanze.num_stanza='$num_stanza' AND consumi.data_c BETWEEN '$data1' AND '$data2'`). It looks like the join with `stanze` is not defined, so it's actually possible it will return _more_ rows than you want after removing the grouping.